# What types are convertible to std::any?

Tags: c++, c++17, llvm

While writing a clang plugin, I noticed that objects of type `llvm::cl::opt<T>` are not convertible to `std::any`, i.e. the following snippet does not compile:

```
#include <any>
#include <string>

#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

int main()
{
  llvm::cl::opt<std::string> opt("o");
  std::any opt_any = opt; // doesn't work!
}
```

I would like to know both why this isn't possible in this specific instance and what criteria a type has to fullfill in general in order to be convertible to `std::any`.

Comment: please include the error message in the question

Comment: @idclev463035818: That depends on the compiler and is not very insightful for both gcc and clang.

Comment: somewhere hidden, the error message just says the same as the answer. Maybe you cannot read it, but perhaps others can and also others might get the similar error so including the error message would make the question more useful for future readers

Comment: note to what @ idclev said: because then others pass-in error in search engine, it would link to here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`llvm::cl::opt` is not copyable.  Both the copy constrcutor and copy assignment operator are marked as `delete`.

`std::any` requires that in construction and assignment that the type be copyable.

---

You could use a `std::unique_ptr<llvm::cl::opt<std::string>>` or `std::shared_ptr<llvm::cl::opt<std::string>>` or even a `std::reference_wrapper` depending on how you want to handle the lifetime of the object.